# Only one javascript tag loading?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have two external .js files & I have linked them properly via my index.html file however only the first script tag loads both .js files work but I can only load one of them in my html file.

Html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Crypto Monitor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="ui left fixed vertical menu">
  <div class="item">
    <img class="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/KpBo4E0.png">
  </div>
  <a class="item">Dashboard</a>
  <a class="item">Exit</a>
  </div>

  <div class="bitcoin container">
  <div class="ui orange center aligned raised segment">
  <img src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/1.png"> <p>Current Bitcoin Price:</p>
  <h3 id="btc" style="color:green">Loading Price...</h3>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="btc.js"></script>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Ethereum container">
  <div class="ui blue center aligned raised segment">
  <img src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/1027.png"> <p>Current Ethereum Price:</p>
  <h3 id="eth" style="color:green">Loading Price...</h3>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="eth.js"></script>
  </div>
  </div>

<div class="ui black center aligned raised segment">
<img src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/52.png">
<p style="color:green;">Current XRP Price:</p>
<p>Loading...</p>
<label for="24 hr change">Change (24HR): loading...</label>
</div>

<div class="ui yellow center aligned raised segment">
<img src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/328.png">
<p>Current Monero Price:</p>
<p style="color:green;">Loading...</p>
<label for="24 hr change">Change (24HR): loading...</label>
</div>

<div class="ui black center aligned raised segment">
<img src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/2.png">
<p>Current Litecoin Price:</p>
<p style="color:green;">Loading...</p>
<label for="24 hr change">Change (24HR): loading...</label>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
body {
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>




</body>
</html>
```

btc.js file:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const axios = require('axios')

function getBTC() {
  axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=USD')
  .then(res => {
    const cryptos = res.data.BTC.USD
    btc.innerText = '$' + cryptos.toLocaleString('en')
  })
}

getBTC()
setinterval(getBTC, 1000);
```

eth.js file:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const axios = require('axios')

function getETH() {
  axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD')
  .then(res => {
    const cryptos = res.data.ETH.USD
    eth.innerText = '$' + cryptos.toLocaleString('en')
  })
}

window.addEventListener("onload", function(){
  console.log('I am loaded');
});

getETH()
setinterval(getETH, 2000);
```

Both .js files work properly however when I include both into index.html only the first script will load.

Edit: https://i.imgur.com/cQ2wmjs.gifv
you can see that the loading price... feature does not work however when I just use one script tag in the index.html file it will load fine.

Comment: _"both .js files work but I can only load one of them in my html file"_ <- what does that mean? How can they both _"work"_ if only one is loaded?

Comment: I suggest you look in your browser console for errors

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same variables `electron`, `path`, and `axios` in both files. You also declare them with `const`, which prohibits reassigning them. So when you try to load the second `.js` file it gets an error due to trying to assign to a `const` variable.

Wrap all the code in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) so each file is in its own scope.

```js
(function() {
  const electron = require('electron')
  const path = require('path')
  const axios = require('axios')

  function getETH() {
    axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD')
      .then(res => {
        const cryptos = res.data.ETH.USD
        eth.innerText = '$' + cryptos.toLocaleString('en')
      })
  }

  window.addEventListener("onload", function() {
    console.log('I am loaded');
  });

  getETH()
  setinterval(getETH, 2000);
})();
```

Comment: OP isn't using `type="module"` so it's unlikely `require()` will work in either script. Even then, I'm pretty sure you can only use `import`

Comment: He claims that loading just one of them by itself works.

Comment: Both .js functions work as intended only if tested with one script tag inside html file however if I use two script tags only one of the js files will load in console I get this error

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'electron' has already been declared`

I get that SyntaxError even when using 'let' instead of 'const' in both files.

Comment: OK, change the scripts to use an IIFE so they're in different scopes.

Comment: Thanks Barmar you helped me complete my first JS application can't describe the feeling :)